# Vue Test Utils, Keydown event no longer triggered by keyCode in test

Tags: keydown, vue-test-utils

In test environment, keydown event no longer triggered by keyCode after updated `vue-test-utils` to version `1.0.0-beta.26` or above, example:

Vue

```
  <div @keydown="onKeydown"></div>
```

Scripts

```js
  public onKeydown (event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
      this.keyName = 'enter'
    } else if(event.keyCode === 67) {
      this.keyName = 'c'
    }
  }
```

Previous version, all test PASS with keyCode as parameter.

```
// version 1.0.0-beta.25
const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld)
wrapper.find('div').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 13 })
expect(wrapper.vm.keyName).toBe('enter') // PASS

wrapper.find('div').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: '67' })
expect(wrapper.vm.keyName).toBe('c')  // PASS
```

After version updated, my test now FAILED.

Tried use `keydown.enter`, it work for `enter` key but doesn't work for 'c' key.

```
// version 1.0.0-beta.26
wrapper.find('div').trigger('keydown.enter')
expect(wrapper.vm.keyName).toBe('enter') // PASS

wrapper.find('div').trigger('keydown.c')
expect(wrapper.vm.keyName).toBe('c')  // FAILED
```

Any suggestion how to trigger keydown event with `a-z` key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass `key` as an option. From the [official docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-key-mouse-and-other-dom-events)

```js
it('Magic character "a" sets quantity to 13', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(QuantityComponent)

    wrapper.trigger('keydown', {
      key: 'a'
    })

    expect(wrapper.vm.quantity).toBe(13)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I should avoid using `event.keyCode`, it's been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).